# Make a div expand to fill its content?

Tags: html, css

I have a video and I want it to take up 100% of width but when i put 100% in the css code the margin expands(video doesn't even stretch) enabling users to scroll horizontally .

The css for my webpage;

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;} //for html and body
```

// this is where the video(id=trailer) is placed

```
#screen1 {  
background: #07B63B;
}

#screen1 p {
padding-top: 200px;
}
```

// the css of trailer currently

```
#trailer {
position: relative;
top: 10px; 
width: 100%;
}
```

// html of trailer

```
<video id="trailer" width="985" height="400" controls autoplay>
<!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

NOTE* There is also a white bar at the top where i put my games logo on which takes up quite a lot of the screen1 height but that surely should not effect it, right?.

I would remove if I was able to center the logo on the video giving it a white circular background with strong opacity to highlight the logo.

IMAGE: http(semi-colon)//prntscr.com/3wcazn

i would greatly appreciate any help provided!

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking, a running example would help

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bLT7J/ ? It seems to be a problem with `#screen1` and `#screen1 p`, have you given a width to those?